# How to solve this sql?

Tags: sql, t-sql

i need to filter a sql query with this condition:

- MyField <> '%Not Able%"
- AND MyField = '%Able%"

Obviously i can't apply this filter...

Comment: i' say that you have to use the LIKE and NOT like operator but whithout more details it's hard to guess. can you post the full request and your error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of like oprator of sql over here

```
select * from (
SELECT * FROM tableanme
        WHERE MyField LIKE '%Able%' 
          )d where MyField NOT LIKE '%Not Able%'
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is that %ABLE% is contained in %NOT ABLE% ... i solved my question using a nested Sql !

Answer (score 0):

the bits you need are

```
WHERE     MyField LIKE '%Able%'
          AND MyField NOT LIKE '%Not Able%'
```